# How to update a plotly dash app with new data from a database

Tags: python, flask, psycopg2, plotly-dash

I have a Flask app (Plotly Dash) that fetches data from a DB which gets updated every day. Deployed on AWS, I run the app with gunicorn/nginx. Problem is, the data used in the app are from the latest gunicorn run, not the latest in the DB.

A solution I thought is adding an attribute to gunicorn command (eg. --reload) with a timer, to auto-restart gunicorn daily. Is this possible, or even, are there any other workarounds?

**SOLUTION** : https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-refresh-data-on-fly/13069

Comment: Is modifying the application to restart itself after some time or restart on e.g. a trigger (incoming HTTP request on /service/restart for example) a possibility?

Comment: Re-running the script on page refresh would be ideal essentially.

Comment: Can you pack the script in the flask route? How long does processing of the data take, is it just pulling something from the DB or is there some "longer" processing involved? Can you show some code of the flask route and of the DB connection?

Comment: The process is, 

- opening a connection with the db with psycopg2, 
- create a cursor, 
- use the cursor to run 4 separate queries. 

Data from the queries are stored in local pandas DataFrames, get aggregated based on specific needs and then visualized. 

Whole process might take up to 2 minutes.

There is no Flask routing, I initialize a Flask(_name_) server which hosts a Plotly Dash app

Comment: You can reload gunicorn by sending SIGHUP, so you could use cron or whatever works on AWS to send SIGHUP every day at e.g. 1AM. You could also try to reload the plotly dash app, but I personally have no experience with it. If you want to go that route I would suggest editing the question to mention plotly and more details and specifically ask how to reload it. 2 minutes is probably too long to run it on every page refresh, but you could refresh hourly or daily without restarting gunicorn. I would guess the outcome is the same for both ways.

Comment: Looking up to that, thank you very much!

Comment: Could you post your solution to as an answer to your own question (and accept it)? That way it's visible that this question has a solution and hopefully might help others.

Answer (score 1):

You can signal gunicorn to reload with [the SIGHUP signal](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/signals.html). To try it out manually you can do that e.g. with `killall -s 1 gunicorn`, to reload everyday you probably want to use something like [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or some AWS specific service. It seems like AWS [has some documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html) on that.

Using `killall` is suboptimal, as it operates on the name of the process. It can break if the name changes (e.g. gunicorn renames itself to be identified with the application name) or if there are more than one gunicorn running. But as long as this is the only usecase for the server, it should be fine.